# Временная задержка в C# или задержка действия Hover для кнопки в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать задержку для кнопки, срабатываемой при наведении курсора (ClickMode Hover).

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(); не подходит, потому что при этом замирает курсор, а его то как раз и нужно успеть убрать.

Comment: что за задержка?
System.Timers.Timer - подойдёт как решение?

Comment: прочитал на msdn и попробовал на всякий случай тупо вставить - как и ожидалось - результата ноль.

насколько я понимаю, Timer мог бы помочь, например, отсрочить отправку какого-то сообщения в программе... но в данном случае речь ведь идет о простом нажатии кнопки, и т.к. система по умолчанию не ждет ответа Timer'а, то и задержки не происходит.

Comment: p.s. поясню ситуацию по подробней: я имею в программе WPF проекта две кнопки. Одна над другой. Я не стал мучиться с ToggleButton и тупо поставил исчезновение одной кнопки при нажатии и появление второй. С точки зрения юзера получается кнопка с двумя состояниями: ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ. Ставлю необходимым действием с одной из кнопок (допустим ВКЛ) наведение мыши, вместо клика. Но получается в итоге, что выключить ее невозможно - нажимаешь кнопку ВЫКЛ, не успеваешь отвести мышь, и кнопка ВКЛ срабатывает автоматически. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: просто жуть

Comment: звучит как просто странное решение. ровно как и задача, честно говоря.
оставь одну кнопку и добейся нужного тебе поведения и отображения, не надо копать в сторону этого костыля с двумя кнопками.

если же всё таки хочется извращений, в обработчиках можешь завести флаг, который не пропустит лишние нажатия и т.п.

Comment: Что вы называете словом «задержка»? Задержка _чего_? От этого зависит ответ.